# reverse an incomplete list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I was searching but I found nothing about how to reverse an incomplete list in prolog.
Here is what I did:

```
incomplete_reverse([L|T],Res):-nonvar(L),!,incomplete_reverse(T,Res1),
                           append(Res1,[L],Res).
incomplete_reverse(L,L):-var(L).
```

This just reverses the list, but I need it to be deterministic and the reversed list must be also an incomplete list. How can I do that?

Comment: [1,2,3|_]->incomplete list input:    [3,2,1|_] -> incomplete list output

Comment: What do you you want the result of `incomplete_reverse([1,2,3|_], R)` to look like?

Comment: lurker the answer to that querry should be [3,2,1|_]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion is that you get acquainted with *difference lists* and their applications, if not already. In a nutshell, a difference list is an open list where you keep track of the open end. For example, an empty list can be represented by `Tail-Tail`. A list with three elements, say, the atoms `a`, `b`, and `c`, can be represented as `[a,b,c| Tail]-Tail`. This allows e.g. O(1) appending of two lists and adding an element to the end of the list.

But going back to your question, here is some code for you to play with:

```
reverse_open_list([Element| Rest], Stack, [Element| Stack]) :-
    var(Rest),
    !.
reverse_open_list([Element| Rest], Stack, Reverse) :-
    reverse_open_list(Rest, [Element| Stack], Reverse).
```

A sample query:

```
?- reverse_open_list([a,b,c|_], Tail, Reverse).
Reverse = [c, b, a| Tail].
```

As the open tail is also returned, you can trivially go from the reversed list to a difference list.

Comment: it is supposed that I do not use the difference list.

Comment: @VladTamas The code I posted **doesn't** use a difference list. It just makes it easy to **construct** one from the result. You can simply call the `reverse_open_list/3` with an anonymous variable in the second argument.